# MPI Spawn: Not enough slots available / All which nodes are allocated for this job are already filled

Tags: mpi, spawn

I am trying use MPI's Spawn functionality to run subprocesses that also use MPI. I am using MPI 2x and dynamic process management.

I have a master process (maybe I should say "master program") that runs in python (via `mpi4py`) that uses MPI to communicate between cores. This master process/program runs on 16 cores, and it will *also* make `MPI_Comm_spawn_multiple` calls to C and Fortran programs (which also use MPI). While the C and Fortran processes run, the master python program waits until they are finished.

A little more explicitly, the master python program does two primary things:

1. Uses MPI to do preprocessing for the spawning in step (2). `MPI_Barrier` is called after this preprocessing to ensure that all ranks have finished their preprocessing before step (2) begins. Note that the preprocessing is distributed across all 16 cores, and at the end of the preprocessing the resulting information is passed back to the root rank (e.g. `rank == 0`).
2. After the preprocessing, the root rank spawns 4 workers, each of which use 4 cores (i.e. all 16 cores are needed to run all 4 processes at the same time). This is done via `MPI_Comm_spawn_multiple` and these workers use MPI to communicate within their 4 cores. In the master python program, only `rank == 0` spawns the C and Fortran subprocesses, and an `MPI_Barrier` is called after the spawn on all ranks so that all the `rank != 0` cores wait until the spawned processes finish before they continue execution.
3. Repeat (1) and (2) many many times in a for loop.

---

**The issue I am having** is that if I use `mpiexec -np 16` to start the master python program, all the cores are being taken up by the master program and I get the error:

> All nodes which are allocated for this job are already filled.

when the program hits the `MPI_Comm_spawn_multiple` line.

If I use any other value less than 16 for `-np`, then only some of the cores are allocated and some are available (but I still need all 16), so I get a similar error:

> There are not enough slots available in the system to satisfy the 4 slots 
>   that were requested by the application:
>      /home/username/anaconda/envs/myenvironment/bin/python
>
> Either request fewer slots for your application, or make more slots available
>   for use.

So it seems like even though I am going to run `MPI_Barrier` in step (2) to block until the spawned processes finish, MPI still thinks those cores are being used and won't allocate another process on top of them. Is there a way to fix this?

(If the answer is hostfiles, could you please explain them for me? I am not understanding the full idea and how they might be useful here.)

Comment: **Why?** What you are trying to do seems like a bad solution,  there is probably a better way to achieve whatever it is you actually need. Please also clarify your use of threads. Note that in MPI 1 process = 1 rank, so there cannot be a master process with multiple ranks.

Comment: @Zulan, the "why" requires an in-depth explanation that I believe is out of the scope of this post and will take > a page to explain. In brief, this parallelization technique will be integrated into a GA optimization framework for materials science research. I have done over a month of digging into this problem and I am relatively confident that this is the correct technique. I hope I have clarified the threads in my edited post. You will see that this question pertains to Python, C, and Fortran MPI software, which is why I included the tags you deleted, because it might pertain to others.

Comment: I think I now understand what you want to do. One additional issue with your approach, even if you fix the particular issue you observe, is that most MPI implementations have terrible performance when working in oversubscribed fashion. Unless you configure/tuned the setup very carefully, the original pre-processing ranks will use CPU cycles while waiting at the barrier, slowing down your workers. You also have to consider the batch system, if that is supposed to be a portable infrastructure used in HPC. I'm afraid I can't think of a good solution to your actual problem.

Comment: @Zulan, thanks for the help and letting me know. I did not know that oversubscribing was a serious issue. I'll keep thinking about it and asking around.

Answer (score 1):

This is the poster of this question. I found out that I can use `-oversubscribe` as an argument to `mpiexec` to avoid these errors, but as Zulan mentioned in his comments, this could be a poor decision.

In addition, I don't know if the cores are being subscribed like I want them to be. For example, maybe all 4 C/Fortran processes are being run on the same 4 cores. I don't know how to tell.

Comment: On linux, you can use `sched_getaffinity` to check what cores are assigned to a thread. For example OpenMPI's `mpiexec` has the options `--report-bindings` and `--bind-to` to report and control the binding.

Answer (score 0):

Most MPIs have a parameter `-usize 123` for the `mpiexec` program that indicates the size of the "universe", which can be larger than the world communicator. In that case you can spawn extra processes up to the size of the universe. You can query the size of the universe:

```
int universe_size, *universe_size_attr,uflag; 
MPI_Comm_get_attr(comm_world,MPI_UNIVERSE_SIZE,
      &universe_size_attr,&uflag);
universe_size = *universe_size_attr;
```